# Free tool to interrogate/browse active directory groups?

Tags: active-directory

I want to know who are the members of some AD group. Which free tool can I use to do this?

Addition:

I am not an AD admin and I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some LDAP browsers and the one which was so easy to use was LDAP brower from LDAPSoft.

Answer (score 2):

Try the active directory browser from microsoft:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ADUC (Active Directory Users and Computers) MMC snap-in is in the ADMINPAK.MSI (Win2003) or RSAT (Win2008), both from Microsoft. LDP.EXE also is a one-EXE in the Support Tools, again MS.

Now. Neither will chase trust "member-of" memberships.

Comment: +1, AD Users and Computers is pretty good.  I don't see a reason to need to script this or use any command-line tools based on the original info.

Answer (score 1):

All the tools you need are already on your DCs.

See my [previous answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/71596/clean-up-active-directory/71608#71608) related to this.  In your case the command would be similar to this:

```
dsquery group -name "myGroup" | dsget group -members -expand
```

PS.  The `-expand` will display the recursive list of members - so if you have a group called *anotherGroup* that is a member of *myGroup*, it'll show you all the members of *anotherGroup* too.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ldapsearch` and Ruby's LDAP modules to search AD for information.  You might want to try one of the free LDAP "Editors" like [led](http://sourceforge.net/projects/led/) or [LDAP Explorer Tool](http://ldaptool.sourceforge.net/).